# How should we tag "bad things in food"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that we have a few questions about "bad things" in/on food, sometimes seeking suggestions on ways to deal with that. Whereas the nutrition tag is about getting sufficient nutrients, these questions seem to be about avoiding problematic matter. Those things fit into several different categories.

Should we have tags for each of these categories, or one tag for all of the above? Currently the best candidate is the [health](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) tag but I think we can afford a bit more precision.

---

Heavy metal contamination, especially from soils

- [Do some varieties of rice contain less arsenic?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/do-some-varieties-of-rice-contain-less-arsenic)

Organic compounds that affect digestion

- [Which foods benefit from soaking before cooking?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/which-foods-benefit-from-soaking-before-cooking)

Small organisms

- [How to avoid worm infestation from consuming raw vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-to-avoid-worm-infestation-from-consuming-raw-vegetables)

Toxic compounds added through agricultural processes

- [How to remove pesticides and harmful bacteria from fruits and vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-to-remove-pesticides-and-harmful-bacteria-from-fruits-and-vegetables)

Antinutrients (like oxalic acid)

- [How to obtain the best iron absorption from spinach?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/375/how-to-obtain-the-best-iron-absorption-from-spinach)

Harmful compounds produced by cooking

- [Can vegan foods produce heterocyclic amines when cooked?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/555/can-vegan-foods-produce-heterocyclic-amines-when-cooked)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this term has jumped the shark already, but it seems to describe all the use cases.

How about [clean-eating](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-eating)?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions (including examples from other parts of SE):

- food-health
- food-safety
- food-toxicity or nutrient-toxicity or supplement-toxicity
- toxins
- side-effects
- absorption
- ingredients
- food-processing

Comment: I like [food-safety].